# In a Network is Valve a Line or Point in GIS Standard?

Tags: standards, design, database-design

I am designing a GIS Database related to Gas Network. In my opinion Valve equipment is a link equipment which can be closed or opened, So it should be a Line. But lots of clients gather this data as Point layer, which cause lots of problem when analysis the network. Is there any standard that clarify this issue?

Comment: I've never heard of valves or switches being modeled as anything other than a point.

Comment: flow/relief valves have length https://solutions.arcgis.com/gas/help/gas-utility-network-configuration/DataDictionary/DataDictionary/#Flow%20Valve:%204 (some have flaps inside the pipe that can create resistance of flow based on length)